# jquery how to know when each loop complete

Tags: jquery

I am working with the open graph API and trying to run a each loop through a results callback.

I need to know when the loop is complete so I can run a 'success' function.

I thought it would be as easy as comparing the results length against the index but I am having no luck.

What is the best way to do this?

```
function authSuccess() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (result) {
        if (result.data) {
         var l = result.data.length;
         $.each(result.data, function (index, friend) {
                if(l > index ){
                      //do stuff
                }else{
                    //go to success
                     }
            });
        } else { }
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think you probably need a Deferred like [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) if those are asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
$.each(result.data, function (index, friend) {
//do your work
});
//go to success
```

Comment: Have I just been over thinking this? I am away from my computer so I can not test right now but wow... I overlooked that one.. Each is a synchronous action...

Comment: Yup... over-thinking can be a problem sometimes - take regular brakes while programming ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function authSuccess() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (result) {
        if (result.data) {
         var len=0;
         $.each(result.data, function (index, friend) {
                if(!result.data[len+1] ){
//go to success                    

                }else{
                    //do stuff
                     }
len++;
            });
        } else { }
    });
}
```